# ¿Cómo implementar encapsulamiento, polimorfismo y abstracción en Java?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en java que permita realizar las operaciones aritméticas utilizando  los conceptos de la POO (encapsulamiento, herencia, polimorfismo, abstracción) lo empecé a hacer con herencia y no sé cómo agregarle los demás temas.

```
/*
 * principal.java
 */

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class principal {
 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        double NUM1,NUM2,S,D,M,R;
        System.out.println("Ingresar numero 1");
        NUM1=Leer.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingresar numero 2");
        NUM2=Leer.nextDouble();
        clase OP=new clase(NUM1,NUM2);
        S=OP.getSUMA();
        R=OP.getRESTA();
        D=OP.getDIVISION();
        M=OP.getMULTIPLICACION();
        System.out.println("Suma="+S);
        System.out.println("Resta="+R);
        System.out.println("Multiplicacion="+M);
        System.out.println("Division="+D);
    }
 
}
```

```
/*
 * clasenum.java
 */

    public class clasenum {
    protected double A;
    protected double B;
 
    public clasenum(double a,double b){
        this.A=a;
        this.B=b;
    }
 
    public double getA() {
        return A;
    }
 
    public double getB() {
        return B;
    }
 
}
```

```
/*
 * clase.java
 */

    public class clase extends clasenum {
 
    public clase(double a,double b){
        super(a,b);
    }
 
    public double getSUMA(){
        return super.getA()+super.getB();
    }
 
    public double getMULTIPLICACION(){
        return super.getA()*super.getB();
    }
 
    public double getDIVISION(){
        return super.getA()/super.getB();
    }
 
    public double getRESTA(){
        return super.getA()-super.getB();
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes saber es que entre el POO y la programación suelen aparecer algunas inconsistencias.
Segundo, de por si la herencia rompe el encapsulamiento, pero eso es algo mas teorico.
La verdad el ejemplo que elegiste no es el mejor para explicar el tema, te dejo un pequeño código con otro ejemplo mas claro o habitual:

Hace de cuenta que tenes la famosa clase Persona y tenes 2 hijas que heredan de ella, como ser la clase bombero, policia:

```
public abstract class Persona //siempre usa abstract cuando utilices herencia para que no existan instancias de la clase madre
{
    private String nombre, apellido; aca siempre declaralos private
    private int identificacion;

    public void trabajar()
    {
       //lógica general del trabajo
    }
}


public class Bombero
{
    public void trabajar()
    {
        //este método hay que redefinirlo, porque no todas las personas trabajan de la misma forma
        recibirLlamado();
        asistirAlIncendio();
        apagarIncendio();
        volverBase();
    }
}

public class Policia
{
    public void trabajar()
    {
        //este metodo hay que redefinirlo, porque no todas las personas trabajan de la misma forma
        recibirLlamado();
        asistirAlLlamado();
        arrestar();
        llevarLadronPrision();
        volverBase();
    }
}
```

El tema del poliformismo no se ve en tiempo de compilación, esto se observa en ejecución, pero en tu main tendrias que poner algo así como:

```
Persona bombero = new Bombero();//aca tenes el polimorfismo, lo declaras del tipo de la clase madre, pero llamas al new de la clase hija.
Persona policia = new Policia();
```